# firebase.messaging.deleteToken() FAILED when deleting token

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying stop web browser from receiving notification for cases where user logs out/ when oauth refresh token timeout (forced logout).

But when calling method firebase.messaging.deleteToken() with a valid token passed in as parameter, I keep getting errors "A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Requested entity was not found. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed)".

My use case and issue is same as described [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2469), except for the part that I am using firebase 7.24.0.

I can't downgrade to firebase version 7.6.1(it is mentioned as a solution in the above mentioned GitHub thread) because I am also using [messaging.onBackgroundMessage()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background) and it has been added recently.